# Google Maps API: how can I get the departure platforms for public transport?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display the departure platforms for public transport like a train in my Android app.

The data is available since using the google maps website shows me which platforms train depart from but I haven't managed to retrieve this data from the DirectionsResult object.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Update: 
Trying to use postman to retrieve the data resulted in a following object, as you can see there is no departure platform data for the train step while this data is available in google maps website or app itself.

```
{
"geocoded_waypoints": [
    {
        "geocoder_status": "OK",
        "place_id": "ChIJeblWZV1vxkcRbk1MYz1wjbg",
        "types": [
            "bus_station",
            "establishment",
            "point_of_interest",
            "train_station",
            "transit_station"
        ]
    },
    {
        "geocoder_status": "OK",
        "place_id": "ChIJIxbYDbcJxkcRQtHfOo0b58o",
        "types": [
            "bus_station",
            "establishment",
            "point_of_interest",
            "subway_station",
            "train_station",
            "transit_station"
        ]
    }
],
"routes": [
    {
        "bounds": {
            "northeast": {
                "lat": 52.3793179,
                "lng": 5.1124581
            },
            "southwest": {
                "lat": 52.0894115,
                "lng": 4.8996663
            }
        },
        "copyrights": "Map data ©2019",
        "legs": [
            {
                "arrival_time": {
                    "text": "10:25am",
                    "time_zone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
                    "value": 1560846300
                },
                "departure_time": {
                    "text": "9:58am",
                    "time_zone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
                    "value": 1560844680
                },
                "distance": {
                    "text": "39.5 km",
                    "value": 39518
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "27 mins",
                    "value": 1620
                },
                "end_address": "Amsterdam Centraal, Stationsplein, 1012 AB Amsterdam, Netherlands",
                "end_location": {
                    "lat": 52.3781611,
                    "lng": 4.8998801
                },
                "start_address": "Utrecht Central Station, Stationshal 12 12, 3511 CE Utrecht, Netherlands",
                "start_location": {
                    "lat": 52.0894115,
                    "lng": 5.1124581
                },
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "1 m",
                            "value": 0
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "1 min",
                            "value": 0
                        },
                        "end_location": {
                            "lat": 52.0894115,
                            "lng": 5.1124581
                        },
                        "html_instructions": "Walk to Utrecht Central Station",
                        "polyline": {
                            "points": "yu||H{oe^"
                        },
                        "start_location": {
                            "lat": 52.0894115,
                            "lng": 5.1124581
                        },
                        "steps": [
                            {
                                "distance": {
                                    "text": "1 m",
                                    "value": 0
                                },
                                "duration": {
                                    "text": "1 min",
                                    "value": 0
                                },
                                "end_location": {
                                    "lat": 52.0894115,
                                    "lng": 5.1124581
                                },
                                "polyline": {
                                    "points": "yu||H{oe^"
                                },
                                "start_location": {
                                    "lat": 52.0894115,
                                    "lng": 5.1124581
                                },
                                "travel_mode": "WALKING"
                            }
                        ],
                        "travel_mode": "WALKING"
                    },
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "39.5 km",
                            "value": 39518
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "27 mins",
                            "value": 1620
                        },
                        "end_location": {
                            "lat": 52.3792931,
                            "lng": 4.8996663
                        },
                        "html_instructions": "Train towards Alkmaar",
                        "polyline": {
                            "points": "ww||Hu{d^u@eDA@qb@td@eJz^ac@ry@ijEr}IouAltCeWlo@}PhYyQvQkQ`KmRdFo[|Bi^qA_oJ}dBmOaBiVHeZhG}VnNubEhkDusB~eBwuAhmA_fA|bAk\\t]waAx{@cWnOmT`Ii@Ru[lRaGXyF}BqGyKiTadA_L}MuYc@{]kMgJbBsGpH{Nhs@uGfw@O~i@cNvk@DB"
                        },
                        "start_location": {
                            "lat": 52.0897216,
                            "lng": 5.1092273
                        },
                        "transit_details": {
                            "arrival_stop": {
                                "location": {
                                    "lat": 52.3792931,
                                    "lng": 4.8996663
                                },
                                "name": "Amsterdam Centraal"
                            },
                            "arrival_time": {
                                "text": "10:25am",
                                "time_zone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
                                "value": 1560846300
                            },
                            "departure_stop": {
                                "location": {
                                    "lat": 52.0897216,
                                    "lng": 5.1092273
                                },
                                "name": "Utrecht Central Station"
                            },
                            "departure_time": {
                                "text": "9:58am",
                                "time_zone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
                                "value": 1560844680
                            },
                            "headsign": "Alkmaar",
                            "line": {
                                "agencies": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "NS",
                                        "phone": "011 31 30 751 5155",
                                        "url": "http://www.ns.nl/"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "name": "Alkmaar <-> Maastricht IC800",
                                "short_name": "Intercity",
                                "vehicle": {
                                    "icon": "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/rail2.png",
                                    "name": "Train",
                                    "type": "HEAVY_RAIL"
                                }
                            },
                            "num_stops": 2,
                            "trip_short_name": "828"
                        },
                        "travel_mode": "TRANSIT"
                    },
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "1 m",
                            "value": 0
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "1 min",
                            "value": 0
                        },
                        "end_location": {
                            "lat": 52.3781611,
                            "lng": 4.8998801
                        },
                        "html_instructions": "Walk to Amsterdam Centraal, Stationsplein, 1012 AB Amsterdam, Netherlands",
                        "polyline": {
                            "points": "obu~Hg_|\\"
                        },
                        "start_location": {
                            "lat": 52.3781611,
                            "lng": 4.8998801
                        },
                        "steps": [
                            {
                                "distance": {
                                    "text": "1 m",
                                    "value": 0
                                },
                                "duration": {
                                    "text": "1 min",
                                    "value": 0
                                },
                                "end_location": {
                                    "lat": 52.3781611,
                                    "lng": 4.8998801
                                },
                                "polyline": {
                                    "points": "obu~Hg_|\\"
                                },
                                "start_location": {
                                    "lat": 52.3781611,
                                    "lng": 4.8998801
                                },
                                "travel_mode": "WALKING"
                            }
                        ],
                        "travel_mode": "WALKING"
                    }
                ],
                "traffic_speed_entry": [],
                "via_waypoint": []
            }
        ],
        "overview_polyline": {
            "points": "yu||H{oe^}@dSu@eDsb@vd@eJz^ac@ry@y`H`sNeWlo@}PhYyQvQkQ`KmRdFo[|Bi^qA_oJ}dBmOaBiVHeZhG}VnNubEhkDusB~eBwuAhmA_fA|bAk\\t]waAx{@cWnOmT`Ii@Ru[lRaGXyF}BqGyKiTadA_L}MuYc@{]kMgJbBsGpH{Nhs@uGfw@O~i@cNvk@DB`Fi@"
        },
        "summary": "",
        "warnings": [
            "Walking directions are in beta. Use caution – This route may be missing sidewalks or pedestrian paths."
        ],
        "waypoint_order": []
    }
],
"status": "OK"
```

}

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have tried delving deep into the DirectionsResult object, looking for example at the transit details of every leg. I also tried using postman for a request to the web api to clear things up but this gives me results like in the update of my question. This does not contain a departure platform in the transit details of the train step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this information is not available via Directions API at the moment. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to add boarding platform information created in 2016:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829155

It looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task. Feel free to star the feature request in Google issue tracker to add your vote. Hopefully one day Google will implement it.